# CentOS 6 - libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

I've a CentOS6 server for 5 years without problems but it suddenly started throwing errors on `yum update`.

This is the output of yum update:

```
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libdc1394-2.2.2-3.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by smp_utils-libs-0.98-3.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by sshpass-1.05-5.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by fdupes-1.51-6.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by arj-3.10.22-22.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by wireless-tools-1:29-13.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by wireless-tools-1:29-13.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libwnck-2.31.0-1.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libc-client-2007f-4.el7.1.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by libc-client-2007f-4.el7.1.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by smp_utils-0.98-3.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libmcrypt-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by unique-1.1.6-10.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by xclip-0.12-5.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libva-1.2.1-3.el7.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libtidy-0.99.0-31.20091203.el7.x86_64
```

I already tried using `yum --skip-broken` without success.
Server's `libc.so.6` is 2.12 and there's no update.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You installed the EPEL repository for CentOS 7, but you are running CentOS 6.

Remove the `epel-release` package and/or the EPEL repo files from `/etc/yum.repos.d`, and try again with the correct package.